# selected Item in single picker is null

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have single picker when the user select type it will update label but when I select item it equal null to label

```
    //update label type
    NSInteger row  = [singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
   NSString *selected = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
   NSString *strTypeSelected  = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",selected];


    typelabel.text =strTypeSelected;
```

Comment: once check with NSLog.

Comment: Did you check your pickerData?
It can contain empty data for the specified row.

Comment: If selected is a valid string (which you should check with a log) then the next line, *strTypeSelected = ... is completely unnecessary. You already have a string, why are you creating another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
txtField1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrData objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
```

Check `picker.delegate = self;` in .m file -> `viewDidLoad` method.

Check in .h File

```
...Controller<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {...
```

It may be help you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you give outlet and datasource to this singlePicker object of `UIPickerView` and then try this code..

```
typelabel.text = [pickerData  objectAtIndex:[singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

Comment: @darkSlayer you check that give the delegate and datasource to your UIPickerView object and try above code??